# How to Save String to Beginning of CoreData Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I am developing a to-do list app for iOS and I am using CoreData to save the lists and to-do's. I am displaying this in a collection view which gets data from an array linked to the CoreData entity. The problem is that when you create a list or to-do, it saves but will go to the bottom of the screen, I assume this is because when '.saveContext' is run the string being saved will go to the end of the array (basically appending it), is there a way to specify it to save to the beginning of the array? Sort of like myArray.insert("hello", at: 0) instead of myArray.append("hello")

Comment: You should add a `createdDate` or similar date attribute to your item object, then you can sort by this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change saving order of `CoreData` but you can simply call `reverse()` on your `CoreData`'s fetched array to show last entry on first.

```
self.yourArray = try! context.fetch(request)
self.yourArray.reverse() //Now last entry will show first
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a fetch request to get the lists or todos, you can specify an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the fetched objects in any order. You can set a `creationDate` property on lists and todos (set this property to `NSDate()` when you create the object) and then sort on that key:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
let request = ...// your NSFetchedRequest
request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

Good luck!